# How to set an Xcode attribute in CMake for a specific configuration?

Tags: xcode, configuration, build-process, cmake

I'm using CMake to generate an Xcode project, and I use

```
set_target_properties(myproj PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_WHATEVER "some value")
```

to explicitly set a build setting. I'd like to only set it for a particular configuration, similar to using

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MYCONFIG "-O2")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not presently possible (as of CMake 2.8.4-rc2), but as of CMake 2.8.5, it will be possible:

```
XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_FOO[variant=Debug]
```

For more info, see this feature request in CMake's bug tracker:
http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=8179

Monitor that issue in the bug tracker to be notified when it gets implemented.

Comment: Still not working correctly, at least for me with CMake 2.8.10.2 - specifying [variant=Debug] still applies the same property on all configurations.

Comment: Someone has captured this also here http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-October/046737.html

Comment: @lef try 2.8.12.1, I think it's fixed